# Is there a way to convert a JSON string into a Mongo extended JSON using Go?

Tags: json, go, mongo-go

I have a sample JSON body that contains some strings. I want some of the strings to be converted into Mongo Extended JSON. For example, the JSON body passed in is the following:

```
{
    "GuidBinary": "734cba69-4851-4869-8d0e-e870d6fb3065",
    "DateTime": "12/12/2012",
    "RegularString": "abcd"
}
```

And I want to convert this into

```
{
    "GuidBinary": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "<payload>",
            "subType": 0x03
        }
    },
    "DateTime": {"$date": "<ISO-8601 Date/Time Format>"},
    "RegularString": "abcd"
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Go, either through a package like mongo-go-driver or another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's part of the official `mongo-go` driver. Generating this *extended JSON* is published as the [`bson.MarshalExtJSON()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#MarshalExtJSON) function.

Example using it:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "GuidBinary":    []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    "DateTime":      time.Now(),
    "RegularString": "abcd",
}

out, err := bson.MarshalExtJSON(m, false, false)
fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9rZfWkLzz0m)):

```
{"DateTime":{"$date":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"},"RegularString":"abcd",
    "GuidBinary":{"$binary":{"base64":"AQIDBAU=","subType":"00"}}} <nil>
```

So what you need to do is unmarshal your original JSON (using the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package), and you need to do some post processing on it: `GuidBinary` is a regular string in the input JSON, but it represents a UUID. You need to parse it into a UUID value (there are probably lots of libraries for this).

You also need to convert (parse) the `DateTime` which is also given as a JSON text in the input, but it represents a date. Use [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) for this. And now you can call `bson.MarshalExtJSON()` to generate the extended JSON.

Comment: Suppose I want to do the post-processing as part of the step of unmarshalling the original JSON. Do you have a recommendation on how to do this? I was thinking of creating string types for the binary data and the dates, then setting up a custom unmarshaller on those string types, but I'm not too certain how that works.

Comment: @RiaruNeimu It would be enough to unmarshal into a simple map or struct, and do the post processing part manually, to create the UUID and `time.Time` values, and pass the new struct or map to `MarshalExtJSON()`.